# How can i get an input element from a component in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of components `<Task />` each one of them has unique key `<Task key={id} />`, The component `Task` has an input element inside of it `(<div><input type="text" /></div>)`, if i rendered 4 components of `Task` how can i get the input element value of them by the key?

```
this.props.tasks.map((i) => {return (<Task key={i} />);
```

Task.jsx:

```
<Form.TextArea id={`newReplyId${this.props.taskId}`} />{' '}
```

My Question: I want to delete the TextArea `id` and get this element by the key of the component?

Comment: Could you include your code in the question?

Comment: I updated the question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give the `Task` an `onChange` prop which is a function to call that will give the event and the index of the task in your `tasks` array, so you can update the appropriate task in state.

**Example**

```js
function Task({ task, onChange }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={task} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

class Tasks extends React.Component {
  state = { tasks: ["", "", "", ""] };

  onChange = (event, index) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    this.setState(previousState => {
      const tasks = [...previousState.tasks];
      tasks[index] = value;
      return { tasks };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.tasks.map((task, index) => (
          <Task
            key={index}
            task={task}
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e, index)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Tasks />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

pass a method to  component onchange

```
this.props.tasks.map((i) => {return (<Task key={i} _onChange={this._onChange}/>);
```

and handle it in the task component to transfer the key and thevalue changed

```
_onChange(){
    this.props._onChange(data,index);
}
```